# angular create a service which return html from template

Tags: angular

I use a service to transform an html string.

I want my service able to load templates and use  the html from those templates in order to modify the html string in some way.

I tried to use the dynamic-component-loader as explained in https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader. It works well, but the dynamic component return values only after the viewRendering.

I want this to be done before!

Is there a way to do that?

Here a working base:
https://angular-yczh7x.stackblitz.io

Comment: Can you post some code in order to understand what you want to obtain exactly? There is config method to run code before.

Comment: This sounds like an instance of an X-Y problem. What do you actually want to achieve with this? Most likely there is another way.

Comment: I had stackblitz... I want to detect some special tag in user html input and transform those into some template

Comment: you mean inside textarea?

Comment: [innerHTML]="service.getHtml()" is not enough ?

Comment: @Whisher No because I want my text input responsive of my new html. It is not predefined

Comment: Why don't you use a directive instead?